# How to add Composite primary key in YII Framework

Tags: database-design, activerecord, yii, gii

I am stuck in creating composite primary key in yii...i have following tables..

```
**Branche**
id
name

**Item**
id
name

**branch_item**
branch_id
item_id
```

how to create **branch_item** in yii with composite primary key...(and crud with gii)

is it ok if i create table like this...

```
**branch_item**
id (this is the primary key)
branch_id (unique key)
item_id (unique key)
```

what is the best way create composite id or create id with unique keys...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [mentioned in yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#defining-ar-class), a bit not highlighted through.

In short, just ovveride method `primaryKey` like that:

```php
public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('pk1', 'pk2');
}
```

Also see [Yii Model with composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985304/yii-model-with-composite-primary-key)

Comment: Yes, many aspects of model are declared by ovveriding `CActiveRecord` functions.

Comment: You can create a Unique Index instead of composite primary key :)